# Toggle tow difference classes simultaneosly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I present a question with multiple possible/correct answers to users. After they submit the chosen answers, I need to display the correct answers to them. In order to do this, I mark the answers with two different classes **sequentially**, but I need to do the class togglings **simultaneously**.

The logic:

1. The answers they've chosen and were correct are marked with `.answer-correct-selected`
2. The answers they haven't had chosen but actually were correct are marked with - `.answer-correct`

Here is the code:

```javascript
$correctSelectedAnswers   = $('Select the correct selected answers..');
$correctUnSelectedAnswers = $('Select the correct unselected answers..');

// I want these to run simultaneously
$correctSelectedAnswers.toggleClass('answer-correct', 500);
$correctUnSelectedAnswers.toggleClass('answer-correct-selected', 500);
```

How can I run the bottom two lines of the above code **simultaneously**?

Comment: Is there a reason you need both classes applied simultaneously? Is it related to the visual rendering from the CSS tied to those classes? JavaScript being single-threaded, having things happen simultaneously is non-trivial.

Comment: @jstlaurent Everything works good right now, but I imagine, that the best practice would be these things to happen simultaneously. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I've honestly never bothered to try to synchronize updates to element classes. Your JS is being run in a single thread and you actually have no control over **when** the browser will actually update the DOM with whatever changes you've made, nor in which order the browser will process them. In most case, those changes will only apply when the JS is done running, so there will be no difference.

Comment: @jstlaurent I see, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) could be used to tap into multiple cores, and thus possibly accomplishing some level of parallelism, you should think of JavaScript as single threaded (in part because it is). In this case, [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) is not even an option because you can't interact with the DOM outside of the main thread.

So to answer your question, don't try to run anything simultaneously. Assuming you don't have millions of elements that will be affected, those two calls you have there will appear to be "simultaneous" to your users.

Not in the scope of this question, but your use of jQuery's [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) could be causing some ambiguity in the code, the value of "500" doesn't make much sense as the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. As of the "500" parameter, I am using JQuery-UI, that modifies the standard `toggleClass` of the vanilla JQuery, hence this parameter.

Comment: @AlexanderLomia =O that explains it! And no problem.